# No such file or directory - terminal won't recognize directory

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

When I simply try to `cd` into a directory on my desktop (`cd` command + drag folder to terminal to generate file path) I get an error that says "No such file or directory" however, as you can see in the screenshot the folder is there on my desktop.  What could be the problem?  Thanks. [image: directory and mac terminal]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you have to put a space after the cd command, otherwise the Desktop is available with `~/Desktop` on macos shell

Comment: Worked!  What a simple fix. Thank you.